# Инструменты для работы с Google Chrome

Tags: python, google-chrome

Есть ли какие-нибудь сторонние инструменты для работы с браузером помимо selenium. Я пишу бота для быстрой покупки вещей с одного сайта и так-как selenium все-таки предназначен для тестирования, мне это очень сильно мешает, это сильно влияет на скорость потому что появляется каптча и всякое такое. Буду рад услышать альтернативные способы.

Comment: Единственный способ избавиться от капчи — попросить администратора сайта выключить капчу. Ваш Капитан Очевидность.

Comment: @andreymal я бы с радостью попросил будь у меня его контакты,правда, мне кажется, он откажется

Comment: Конечно откажется, потому что капча стоит именно для защиты от таких как вы.

Comment: @andreymal дай бог тебе здоровья, Андрюха

Answer (score 1):

Могу предложить попробовать Cypress. По удобству - очень классная штука. Единственный момент - Cypress работает только на JS. Ваш JS скрипт внедряется в JS сайта и прокручивает сценарий.